# JS_Parse_Error uglify Angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, angular, gulp-uglify

I am getting started with Angular 2. This is my Angular 2 component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { };
```

which translated in Javascript file to:

```
System.register(['angular2/core'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
        var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
        if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
        else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
        return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
    };
    var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
        if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
    };
    var core_1;
    var AppComponent;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (core_1_1) {
                core_1 = core_1_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {
            let AppComponent = class AppComponent {
            };
            AppComponent = __decorate([
                core_1.Component({
                    selector: 'my-app',
                    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
                }), 
                __metadata('design:paramtypes', [])
            ], AppComponent);
            exports_1("AppComponent", AppComponent);
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=app.component.js.map
```

When I try to uglify it using this task:

```
gulp.task('uglifyAppLibs', function (done) {
    gulp.src('./wwwroot/app/app.component.js')
    .pipe(gp_uglify())
    .pipe(gp_rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/app"));
});
```

I get this error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:1525:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:1533:11)
    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2025:9)
    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2033:9)
    at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2039:9)
    at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2059:56)
    at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2239:73)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2112:19)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2072:24)
    at block_ (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2352:20)
```

What am I missing here? The translation of ts file to JS is done automatically by the Visual studio editor so it has to be right.

My Gulp and NodeJS versions are all latest downloaded today only.

Comment: Which version of uglify-js and gulp-uglify do you use?

Comment: It works for me with versions: uglify-js (2.6.2) and gulp-uglify (1.5.3)

Comment: I'm getting the same error with gulp-uglify (1.5.3). moreover, I kept removing components to simplify it, and I found the root error stems from the class declaration. I can simply have an empty class, and it will throw this error.